# How to echo a variable from a processing page?

Tags: php, variables, echo

I have a separate file that generates a PDF, saves select information to a database, creates the PDF and then emails it to the user. What I am trying to do is echo the sql statement on the confirmation page.

request.php -> PDF-generation.php -> confirmation.php

The user never sees the PDF generation page.

Here is the function:

```
function LogToDatabase($holding_id, $to_email, $from_email, $subject, $message, $pdf) { 
    //Save record of PDF here
    $db = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, 'webtransaction', DB_HOST);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO 504_pdf_storage (`holding_id`, `to_email`, `from_email`, `subject`, `message`, `pdf`) 
        VALUES(" . $holding_id . "," . $to_email ."," . $from_email ."," . $subject ."," .  $message ."," . $pdf . ");";
    return $db->insert_id;
}
```

I want to echo the variable $sql from PDF-generation.php onto the confirmation.php but a simple "echo $sql;" gives an error saying "Undefined variable"

Please help and thanks!

EDIT: Here is the top of the confirmation page.

```
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');
require_once('../includes/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('../classes/504-send-request.php');
require_once ('../classes/pdf_generator.php');

$mh = new MobileHomeRequest();
$data = $mh->GetTempData($_POST['id']);
$holding_id = $data->SaveToDatabase();
$pdf = new PDFGen(null,$data);
echo $sql;

get_header();

if(!$pdf->RenderPDF()) { ?>
    <script>
        alert('Couldn\'t send your email because our servers seem to be really lame today.');
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Where do you echo that, inside the `LogToDatabase` function?

Comment: I've tried that and I've also tried on the confirmation page. I assume that if I do it on the pdf-generation page it won't show since its just a processing or action page.

Comment: if you just want to see the SQL query in the function, just `var_dump($sql);` then use `exit();` to break the process

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't think its the string itself. I'm having an issue returning the variable. It's stating that it is undefined.

Comment: @Javad I tried that but its not showing the contents of the $sql variable :(

Comment: Then are you sure it goes to this function? There might be some other process. It might be better to debug it by some tools line by line and you will find it

Answer (score 0):

Save the value in a session variable, and then echo out the session variable on the confirmation page.  You'll need `session_start()` at the top of each page.

```
function LogToDatabase($holding_id, $to_email, $from_email, $subject, $message, $pdf) { 
  //Save record of PDF here
  $db = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, 'webtransaction', DB_HOST);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO 504_pdf_storage (`holding_id`, `to_email`, `from_email`, `subject`, `message`, `pdf`) 
    VALUES(" . $holding_id . "," . $to_email ."," . $from_email ."," . $subject ."," .  $message ."," . $pdf . ");";
  //add this
  $_SESSION['savedSQL'] = $sql;
  return $db->insert_id;
}
```

Then on the confirmation page, it's a simple:

```
echo htmlentities($_SESSION['savedSQL'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

**Side Note**

As mentioned in the comments, a `var_dump($sql)` followed by `exit()` would be much better.  Also note the `htmlentities()` to protect against XSS, since it is unknown where the variables in the query are coming from.

Comment: some over complicated way of debuggin

Comment: I agree, a `var_dump()` would be much better.  However, the OP did say he wanted to echo out the statement on the confirmation page, and this *is* one way to do it :)

Comment: I tried that and I get "Notice: Undefined index: savedSQL  on line 11"

Comment: Did you add `session_start()` at the top of each page?  It must be before all other output.

Comment: When it is just at the top of the pdf-generating file it gives just "Notice: Undefined index: savedSQL " but when its on the confirmation page as well it gives an additional error saying that a session was already started.

Comment: there is something completely wrong with your architecture

Comment: Is the confirmation page a stand-alone page, or is it included on a different page?  That would give "session already started".  For the undefined index, is that function being called prior to using the session variable elsewhere?  It would need to be, since that is where the session variable is initialized.

Comment: When the user hits submit the action takes them to the confirmation and the confirmation page handles the call to the PDF-generator page. Its included. I edited my original post so you could see the top of the confirmation page.

Comment: I think wordpress is different than straight php.  Check this for sessions in wp: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-session-in-wordpress